# select with join each runs forever, when removing "each", it works OK.

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a select with left join each that used to run OK.
Now It runs forever, when I remove the "each", it runs OK.

Any idea why? should we remove all our "EACH" clauses? Also for group and other joins? 
This is critical, since this is embedded in our code in many places, and suddenly things runs very slow.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I would recommend specifying `each` or `all` explicitly ever. That's a premature optimization. BigQuery is or should be smart enough to figure out what the best strategy for joining is. That's probably why you are seeing the speedup: letting BigQuery do the heavy lifting, it figures out a faster way of doing so.

Answer (score 0):

JOIN EACH should be used when your table you're joining is too large to be joined.

First, let me explain how the normal JOIN is done. How this works is that if your table is under 8 Megabytes, it is completely sent to each shard that runs parts of your queries. This is quick, this is as efficient as can be, and doesn't really need optimizations on your part. If your table is over 8 MBs, then JOIN doesn't work, because it can't send more than 8 MBs to each shard.

Now, for the "JOIN EACH": No matter if your table is over or under 8 MBs, if you use a JOIN EACH, the system will hash whatever you join on and send only the relevant results to each shard, to minimize the number of joins you run, and to make sure that each shard has ALL the relevant data to work. If you do a join on a parameter with low entropy (everything is similar, so hash results are probably all ending up on the same few shards), there is a chance that your shards are not optimally used (1 shard could query 90% of your data, letting the other X shards to handle 10% of it). If you have tables UNDER 8 MBs, with low entropy, that additional hashing + the inefficient sharding this may cause would explain what's happening.

Basically, as was pointed out by Giovanni..... BQ knows what to do, so let it do its thing :)